# elasticsearch syntax error for filter using both 'and' and 'or'

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to perform a filter using `elasticsearch`, and am getting a syntax error that I cannot seem to correct.  I have tested the individual classes, and they seem to work fine.  What am I doing wrong?

The intention here is to find documents that satisfy three simultaneous conditions: `(field1 == VAL1)`, `(field2 == VAL2)`, and `((field3 == VAL3) || (field3 == VAL4))`.

The message I get is:

> "nested: QueryParsingException[[xxxx] Failed to parse]; nested:
>   JsonParseException[Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting
>   comma to separate ARRAY entries\n at [Source: [B@1acfee60; line: 13,
>   column: 26]]; }]","status":400}"

Thanks!

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/xxxx/yyyy/_search' -d '
{
    "query":
    {
        "filtered":
        {
            "filter":
            {
                "and":
                [
                    { "term": { "field1":"VAL1" } },
                    { "term": { "field2":"VAL2" } },
                    "or":
                    [
                        { "term": { "field3":"VAL3" } },
                        { "term": { "field3":"VAL4" } }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Thanks to Paige Cook, the syntax error is now gone (see below). But the filter still does not match the document. And I have tested both the "and" clause and the "or" clause separately and they both work. I'm confused.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/xxxx/users/_search' -d '
{
    "query":
    {
        "filtered":
        {
            "filter":
            {
                "and":
                [
                    { "term": { "field1":"VAL1" } },
                    { "term": { "field2":"VAL2" } }
                ],
                "or":
                [
                    { "term": { "field3":"VAL3" } },
                    { "term": { "field3":"VAL4" } }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Thank you very much Geert-Jan.  The final working example is:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/xxxx/yyyy/_search' -d '
{
    "query":
    {
        "filtered":
        {
            "filter":
            {
                "and":
                [
                    { "term": { "field1":"VAL1" } },
                    { "term": { "field2":"VAL2" } },
                    {
                        "or":
                        [
                            { "term": { "field3":"VAL3" } },
                            { "term": { "field3":"VAL4" } }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

be careful with the parentheses!

A base filter can only contain 1 filter in this case the `and`. Within that compound-filter you should have 2 base-filters (both `term`) and a compound filter `or`.

Here it is (untested)

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/xxxx/users/_search' -d '
{
    "query":
    {
        "filtered":
        {
            "filter":
            {
                "and":
                [
                    { "term": { "field1":"VAL1" } },
                    { "term": { "field2":"VAL2" } },
                    {
                        "or":
                        [
                            { "term": { "field3":"VAL3" } },
                            { "term": { "field3":"VAL4" } }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yay!  That did it.  Thank you very much Geert-Jan!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the json query you have posted above, you are missing a `],` after the last and term and before your `"or:"` entry. The `"and"` and `"or"` arrays need to be defined separately.

Try this:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/xxxx/yyyy/_search' -d '
{
    "query":
    {
        "filtered":
        {
            "filter":
            {
                "and":
                    [
                        { "term": { "field1":"VAL1" } },
                        { "term": { "field2":"VAL2" } }
                    ],
                "or":
                    [
                        { "term": { "field3":"VAL3" } },
                        { "term": { "field3":"VAL4" } }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paige Cook.  That has solved the syntax error.  But the filter still does not match the document.  And I have tested both the "and" clause and the "or" clause separately and they both work.  I'm confused.

Comment: See answer from Geert-Jan for the correct query syntax, using the compound filter.